# Is there a github markdown language identifier for Common Lisp on Atom?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, atom-editor, github-flavored-markdown

I'm trying to write some code blocks in Common-Lisp using GitHub Markdown on Atom, but if I write

#### ```common-lisp

#### ```cl

it doesn't highlight the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the master list located in the github repo, we find common-lisp here:
https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml#L743

So you need to use: ```common-lisp or ```lisp

for common-lisp in Github Markdown. If this does not show up in your Atom editor during the preview, then you need to install the `language-lisp` package.